# A problem from Applied Asymptotic Analysis by Peter D. Miller (Exercise 1.8)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

[transcribed exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApXK7.png)

> *Exercise 1.8.* Suppose that $\mu$ is a continuous parameter and that for each $\mu \in[0,1]$, we have $f(z, \mu)=O(g(z, \mu))$ as $z \rightarrow z_0$ from $D$. The above proof suggests that it might be true that if the integrals exist in the Riemann sense for all $z$ close enough to $z_0$, then
> $$
> \int_0^1 f(z, \mu) d \mu=O\left(\int_0^1|g(z, \mu)| d \mu\right) \quad \text { as } z \rightarrow z_0 \text { from } D,
> $$
> since the integrals can be approximated by Riemann sums. Under what additional hypotheses on $f(z, \mu)$ and $g(z, \mu)$ can the proof be adapted to the continuous case? Can you find a counterexample?

I am reading Applied Asymptotic Analysis in the series Graduate Studies in Mathematics Volume 75. I'm confused by ex 1.8. I don't think this proposition is true but I can't find a counterexample. However, I find that when $f(z,\mu),g(z,\mu)$ is continuous in $D\times[0,1]$ and $g(z,\mu)\neq0$,the statement is true. Any attempt to find a counterexample will be helpful!

[Here's what the notation means:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy4Ak.png)

> **Definition 1.2** (Big-oh near $\left.z_0\right)$. Let $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ be two complex-valued functions defined in some set $D$ of the complex plane whose closure contains a point $z_0$ (that is, $z_0$ is a limit point of $D$ ). Then we write
> $$
> f(z)=O(g(z)) \quad \text { as } z \rightarrow z_0 \text { from } D
> $$
> if there is a number $\delta>0$ such that
> $$
> f(z)=O(g(z)), \quad z \in D \text { with } 0<\left|z-z_0\right|<\delta,
> $$

<sup>*Miller, Peter D.*, Applied asymptotic analysis, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 75. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-4078-9/hbk). xv, 467 p. (2006). [ZBL1101.41031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1101.41031).</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take
$$f(z,\mu) = \begin{cases}\mu^{z-1}, &z>0 \text{ and } \mu >0,\\ 0, & z\le 0 \text{ or } \mu = 0,\end{cases} \quad g(z,\mu) = 1, \quad D = [-1,1],\quad z_0=0.$$
Then for each fixed $\mu\in(0,1]$, we have $|f(\cdot,\mu)|\le \frac1\mu=O(1)$ (i.e. $f$ is bounded) near $z_0=0$, and similarly for $\mu = 0$, but
$$ \int_0^1 f(z,\mu) d\mu = \begin{cases}\frac1{z},&z>0,\\ 0, &z \le 0,\end{cases}$$
which is unbounded as $z\to 0$.

Comment: Here $\mu$ is not a continuous parameter when $\mu=0$

Comment: @song sorry, can you please explain what is a continuous parameter? $f$ is defined for all $\mu\in[0,1]$